# What is the minimum requirement to compile Kernel modules

Tags: kernel, build, modules

I want to compile a Kernel module.

What is the minimal set of packages that I need to download to succeed?

Cheers,

Stefan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need build-essential and kernel headers.

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential`

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you will need [gcc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gcc) and the kernel headers ([linux-libc-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/linux-libc-dev)).